# Observing camera isFocusing || !isFocusing for androidx.camera.core.Camera

Tags: java, android-camera, androidx

Is there any documentation you guys can help me drive me in the direction? I've only VERY recently implemented AndroidX as I was using the old Camera framework.

I've only found one lead and it was a dead end. I guess I would like to be notified when the camera is focusing and/or when it is focused.

Edit: 
This is my code block where I setup and configure my camera:

```
        Size screen = new Size(txView.getWidth(), txView.getHeight()); //size of the screen

    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
            // We request aspect ratio but no resolution
            .setTargetResolution(screen)
            // Set initial target rotation
            .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
            .build();

    ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
            .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
            // We request aspect ratio but no resolution to match preview config, but letting
            // CameraX optimize for whatever specific resolution best fits our use cases
            .setTargetResolution(screen)
            // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
            // during the lifecycle of this use case
            .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
            .build();

    ImageAnalysis imageAnalyzer = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(screen)
            .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
            .build();

    CameraSelector cameraSelector =
            new CameraSelector.Builder()
                    .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                    .build();
    int count = 0;

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                cameraProvider.unbindAll();

                androidx.camera.core.Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        cameraSelector,
                        preview,
                        imageAnalyzer,
                        imageCapture
                );

                preview.setSurfaceProvider(txView.createSurfaceProvider(camera.getCameraInfo()));
                onCreateTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Still digging but I'm finding that Camera2Interop might help? I actually fell upon it by accident just typing random things on my editor....